# Accessing current HttpContext from HttpActionContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` to check that client applications are authorised to use the API.

As part of the "OnAuthorization" I would like to record the request made in a simple text file in the Web Application's AppData folder.

To do this, I need to access the `Server.MapPath()` but it does not appear to be part of the `HttpActionContext`

Obviously, I could use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(....)` but I was wondering if I was missing something.

```
public class CustomAuth: System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        /* Is this available as part of "actionContext" */
        var Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(....) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done another way:

```
var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/your-path");
```